# Turning Card with Text change -> Looking for QML Logic for Sequential Actions/Animations

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to create some sort of Vocabulary Trainer.

I have a `Card` QML File what shoud represent some kind of a record card where you can see the Vocabulary. When you've answered, the card should turn around 180° and a new Word/Text should be visible on it.

So far I've created a `Rectangle` for the `Card` and a `Transformation` for the `Rotation` split up in two `PropertyAnimation`s.

For the sake of simplicity I just want the animation to happen when I'm clicking on the `Card`. Then the Card turns from 0 to 90 degrees. Afterwards the text should be changed. And at last the `Card` should turn from -90 to 0 degrees. So I'm looking for a logic that allows me to execute an animation, changes a property (text) instantly and executing another animation as a sequence.

Here is my Code so far:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {

    Rectangle {
        id: card
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "grey"
        antialiasing: true

        Text {
            id: question
            text: "test test test"
            anchors.centerIn: card
        }

        transform: Rotation {
            id: rotation
            origin.x: (card.width / 2)
            origin.y: (card.height / 2)
            axis {
                x: 0
                y: 1
                z: 0
            }
            angle: 0
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: card
            onClicked: {
                // Code for Turning Card arround
                rotate_away.start()
                question.text = "abcabcabc"
                rotate_new.start()
            }
        }

        PropertyAnimation {
            id: rotate_away
            target: rotation
            properties: "angle"
            from: 0
            to: 90
            duration: 1000
        }

        PropertyAnimation {
            id: rotate_new
            target: rotation
            properties: "angle"
            from: -90
            to: 0
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is this part:

```
        rotate_away.start()
        question.text = "abcabcabc"
        rotate_new.start()
```

The text changes but only the 2'nd animation will be executed.

I tried

```
while (rotate_away.running) {}
```

to wait for the 1st animation but then the application gets stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the animations should be played sequently by using `SequentialAnimation`. Please revisit your code as follows:

```
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: card
            onClicked: {
                // Code for Turning Card around
//                rotate_away.start()
//                question.text = "abcabcabc"
//                rotate_new.start()
                fullRotate.start();
            }
        }

        SequentialAnimation {
            id: fullRotate

            PropertyAnimation {
                id: rotate_away
                target: rotation
                properties: "angle"
                from: 0
                to: 90
                duration: 1000
            }

            PropertyAction {
                target: question
                property: "text"
                value: "abcabcabc"
            }

            PropertyAnimation {
                id: rotate_new
                target: rotation
                properties: "angle"
                from: -90
                to: 0
                duration: 1000
            }
        }
```

Also, I recommend [`Flipable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flipable.html) which is meant for flipping effects.

Comment: works like a charm! I've already thought about the SequentialAnimation but I was missing the PropertyAction! I'll also have a look at the Flippable..... looks exactly what I was hoping for.